# How to deal with nested JSON in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

This JSON was given to me by the API.

```
[{'archived': False,
  'associations': {'deals': {'results': [{'id': '2762673039',
                                          'type': 'line_item_to_deal'}]}},
  'createdAt': '2020-08-06T15:05:23.253Z',
  'id': '762434477',
  'properties': {'amount': '100',
                 'createdate': '2020-08-06T15:05:23.253Z',
                 'hs_lastmodifieddate': '2020-08-06T15:05:53.701Z',
                 'hs_object_id': '762434477',
                 'hs_product_id': '133248644',
                 'quantity': '1'},
  'updatedAt': '2020-08-06T15:05:53.701Z'},
```

I want to create a pandas dataframe that has a column for id as well as all of the properties associated with it, in addition to the id nested under "associations". Essentially I want to remove the properties from being nested under properties and the id from being nested under associations (as well as renamed). How would I go about this?

Comment: `pd.json_normalize(data)`?

Comment: Yeah, then I can just rename columns and make tweaks to it. That's a function I was looking for. Gabip's solution is also informative.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can flatten your data after converting it to list of dictionaries:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

response = """[{"id": "133248644",
  "properties": {
            "createdate": "2020-08-06T15:05:23.253Z",
            "description": null,
            "hs_lastmodifieddate": "2020-08-06T15:05:23.253Z",
            "hs_object_id": "133248644",
            "name": "test product",
            "price": "100"},
 "createdAt": "2020-08-06T15:05:23.253Z",
 "updatedAt": "2020-08-06T15:05:23.253Z",
 "archived": false}, 
{"id": "133345685",
 "properties": {
             "createdate": 
             "2020-08-06T18:29:06.773Z", 
             "description": null,
             "hs_lastmodifieddate": "2020-08-06T18:29:06.773Z",
             "hs_object_id": "133345685",
             "name": "TEST PRODUCT 2",
             "price": "2222"},
 "createdAt": "2020-08-06T18:29:06.773Z", 
 "updatedAt": "2020-08-06T18:29:06.773Z",
 "archived": false}]"""

data = json.loads(response)
data_flat = [dict(id=x["id"], **x["properties"]) for x in data]
```

And then you can create a DataFrame out of it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_flat)
print(df)
```

Comment: Ok, I edited my question to reflect an additional problem. I have another id nested under "associations" that I would like to be called "id2" in this dataframe. How would I do that?

Comment: @JacobBayer Does the `results` key contains only one element in the list? if no, how would you like to extract the `id2` from the list (will it be `id2`, `id3`, etc..?)

Comment: `results` has two elements `id` and `type`. Only id is needed. Calling it `id2` is fine. My solution was to use `data_flat= [dict(lineid=x["id"],id2=x["associations"]["deals"]["results"][0]["id"], **x["properties"]) for x in data]`